# how to get records from multiple tables using joins by IQueryOver in nHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

I have three tables:

```
User -> UserId, username

UserGroup -> UserGroupId, GroupName

UserGroupMember -> UserId, UserGroupId
```

I have created the corresponding mappings using nHibernate, but when I try to search for the groupname and retreive the users list which belongs to the particular group, I am receiving error and not able to retrieve the results.

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you post your mappings and the query you are trying to use? This looks like a simple many-to-many relation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about your problem, but I assume that you wanted to select all users of a group with a certain name.

I would do that like this:

```
var users = Session.QueryOver<UserGroupMember>()
      .Fetch(x => x.User).Eager
      .JoinQueryOver(x => x.UserGroup).Where(x => x.GroupName == groupName)
      .List().Select(x => x.User)
```

Using that query, the SQL will be something like this:

```
Select m.*, u.* 
from UserGroupMember m 
         inner join UserGroup g on m.UserGroupId=g.UserGroupId 
         inner join User u on m.UserId = u.UserId 
where g.GroupName='groupName'
```